# Wicket JQWicket - Wicket

Tags: wicket

I have common question on wicket, currently we are uprading our client from wicket 1.5 to 7.10, we have found some functions of jqwicket0.8 are not working. My question is is there any library available which provide similar function of jqwicket which can work on wicket 7.10.

Sorry, the question would be too general and we would like to seek advise from the wicket expert

Answer (score 0):

These are few integrations with JQuery UI:

1. http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/ (actively maintained)
2. https://github.com/wicketstuff/wiquery (maintained as much as it compiles against Wicket 7/8)
3. https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/jquery-parent

Hopefully they provide what you have used from JQWicket.